# Do iOS browsers include EXIF photo metadata via browser upload?

Tags: ios, upload, metadata, exif

I am trying to gleam EXIF metadata from photos uploaded to my server via an iOS device. Does iOS sends EXIF metadata when uploading photos in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photos uploaded, via safari mobile or any IOS web browser, are stripped of most of the metadata including datetime and geolocation. The only metadata you receive is:

- ColorSpace
- Exif IFD Pointer
- Orientation
- PixelXDimension
- PixelYDimension

If you transfer the photo to your desktop browser and upload then the metadata will exist. Also if you use a Hybrid-Native or Native app you can retain photo metadata.

This data was obtained through testing an EXIF data parser in javascript. I couldn't find actual Apple documentation mentioned this "feature"

Comment: Which JavaScript EXIF parser?